# Error en bases de datos acces

Tags: c++, base-de-datos, dev-c++, mdb, c++builder

Hola comunidad de StackOverflow, me cuentro nuevamente en una situacion confusa, realice un programa con bases de datos ACCES. Pero al momento de instalar mi programa en otro equipo me manda el siguiente error. Alguien sabra el porque solamente funciona el programa en mi equipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Moviste el programa pero la base de datos se quedó en tu equipo?

Comment: copio todos los archivos tal y como esta en mi equipo y no se ejecuta. me manda el mismo error.

Comment: En alguna de las configuraciones, debes tener una referencia a una ruta absoluta D:\xxx.xxx.xxx\AGENDA.mdb y eso no va a servir cuando muevas la BD, porque pasa como en este equipo, que la ruta no existe

Comment: @Alfabravo  recomiendas realizar todo el proyecto desde la unidad C:\\xxx.xxx.xxx\AGENDA.mdb

Comment: ¿Tienes el código fuente de la aplicación? Se puede configurar fácilmente para que la base de datos sea por defecto relativa al directorio de la aplicación y, en caso necesario, poder configurar en el registro de Windows un lugar alternativo donde encontrarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu base de datos esta en la ruta D:\AGENDA ARACELY\AGENDA.mdb, en alguna parte de tu programa dejaste esta ruta como estática y en el nuevo equipo donde intentas correrlo ni siquiera existe la unidad D:\

Si necesitas que el programa trabaje en red lo mejor es que crees una unidad compartida en una ruta \unequipocualquiera\AGENDA.mdb

por otro lado la mas fácil es que lo hagas en C:\NOMBREDETUPROGRAMA\ y así puedas instalarlo en cualquier equipo pero en esa misma ruta.

Comment: Por consiguiente que me recomiendas volver a crear la base de datos acces en la.unidad C?

Comment: si, edite la respuesta para ello. la mejor opción y mas fácil es que lo crees en una carpeta en C:\ y debe llamarse igual a como lo creaste en el equipo de desarrollo.

Comment: Lo recurrente sería integrarlo C:\\ archivos de programa\AGENDA. en caso de que el equipo sea de 64 bits. Habría algún problema en la ejecución de la aplicación?

Comment: No te recomiendo que uses esa ruta, por que podría cambiar con el idioma del sistema operativo.

Comment: Busca la forma de poder crear esa ruta de forma dinámica, y de esa forma no tendrás problema de instalar el programa en cualquier lugar